# Does it make sense to have a method with only one line?

Tags: methods

This question came to my mind because I was working on a project, and I created the following method:

```
private void GoToFirstPage() {
    CurrentPage = 0;
}
```

which I use in a few methods related to pagination.

Is it a good idea? Or should I be calling `CurrentPage = 0;` instead in all the method calls?

Comment: I don't see this is a big problem. it is always good to extract common code into a separate method, even in your case it is dull, but dull is beauty isn't it. while it would make a bit more sense to have a method like
public void DisplayNumberedPage(int pageNo){currentPage = pageNo;}

Comment: I say if not why not. The method name is clear and just by looking at the name, you know exactly what the method does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, how likely is it that you'd ever change the implementation of `GoToFirstPage`? For example, if this is, say, a PDF viewer, might the next version have a continuous scrolling mode as well as a page-by-page mode, so you'll keep a CurrentTopLine instead of a CurrentPage? In that case, if you've got `CurrentPage = 0;` in 15 different places, and you have to change all 15 of them to `if (PageMode) CurrentPage = 0; else CurrentTopLine = 0;`, that's a perfect opportunity for stupid bugs to creep into your code because you forgot about 1 of them and only changed 14. If you've got it in a method, you only need to change things in one place.

In some cases, having a name for the method gives you some extra documentation (and unlike a comment, it won't get stale as things change, because you have to keep it up to date or things won't compile). In this case, I don't think that's relevant, because `CurrentPage = 0;` is just as readable and meaningful as `GoToFirstPage();`, but in many cases, it is.

Occasionally, performance is a concern. Function calls aren't free, after all. But in this case, it's hard to imagine it could ever matter. It's not like you're going to call `GoToFirstPage` millions of times in a tight loop, right?

So, if none of these are relevant, how do you decide? The most important factor is probably what's more idiomatic for your language, codebase, etc. In a typical Java program, a function like `GoToFirstPage();` would fit in perfectly, and it might even be implemented as `SetCurrentPage(0);` for another layer of encapsulation. In a typical Python program, the `current_page` property would be part of even the public API of the class. Neither one is necessarily bad or good, and consistency of style is important in keeping your code readable.

Comment: Totally agree. Especially once the program starts to get a many thousand lines long. Having to search and replace all of that gets tiresome.